# Why does this inline-block cause extra height of its parent?

Tags: css

Sample code like this:

```
.c1 {
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.c2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.c3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0; 
}

<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="c3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does the div.c2 appear? It does not exist when  c3 has `display` other than **inline-block**.

Also see this codepan: https://codepen.io/uuhan/pen/ZXWodw

UPDATE:

I add **line-height: 0** to c2, then div.c2 become thinner. But how can I fingure out this height (**6px**, with origin **22px**) of c2 ?

Also see this codepan: https://codepen.io/uuhan/pen/EwKRLK

Answer (score 5):

c2 exists/has a height because it is at least as high as one line of text. If you add `font-size: 0;` to it, it disappears because then it has height 0.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLaJLj

Comment: Got it. Does this mean that inline-block always contains one line in it?

Comment: Well, you can also set `height: 0` instead of the font-size (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLaJMx) , but if you don't do either one, it will be as high as one line of text.

Comment: I add line-height: 0 to c2 class, the height becomes thinner. I wonder how this height (6px, and the origin height, 22px) is calculated?

Comment: I suppose that depends on the browser settings and defaults